# convert scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a matrix (a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix type) which looks like this:

```
(0, 31) 0.000528868711772147
(0, 32) 4.84173520932837e-05
(0, 33) 4.10541590795596e-05
(0, 34) 0.000408771225384504
(0, 35) 0.000795847618707398
:  :
(16086, 118806) 0.00047416210140481
(16086, 118809) 0.00856067420817794
(16086, 118826) 0.00420368450693882
(16086, 131832) 0.00111739160477843
(16086, 131905) 0.00389774479846667
```

I'm trying to pass it to a numpy array. I've tried using both `.toarray()` and `.todense()` but none of them seems to be working since I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to allocate 18.0 GiB for an array with shape (16087, 150360) and data type float64
```

Do you have any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them seems to be working"?  That's too vague of a description.  Is the some sort of error?  working, but unexpected results?

Comment: It is a memory error.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I wanted you to tell the whole world.  Do you understand why?

Comment: Not really, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Doesn't the error explain it?  The dense array is way too large for your memory.  Look at the numbers .  18 GiB.  That's `16087*150360*8/1e9`!

Comment: Take a look at this thread, this may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66165897/scipy-large-sparse-array-dimensions-memoryerror

Answer (score -1):

your ram is not enogh to make such kind of operation devide data in chunk and do this operation chuck by chunk